# What constraints do I use for this?

Tags: ios, autolayout

What constraints do I use to make the icons stay positioned in the middle of the scrollview like in the photo below for all different sized (3.5, 4, 5.5, etc.) screens.

**Note: All the icons are in a scrollview.**

[image]

Please name all of them (for each icon, if necessary) I've tried multiple but they didn't work. (I forgot which ones)

Comment: There's very little information in this question — how did you achieve what you showed in the screenshot? What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: The old way was to put them inside a view, then center the view. New with Xcode 7 though, there are [stack views](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/).

Comment: You should use "horizontal center in container" and then update constraints by clicking on item and "cmd="

Comment: put them in a stack view (or a regular view if you are using iOS <9) and align the stack view to the horizontal center of the superview.